# Using C Struct inside struct causes segmentation fault error

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

Here is the structure of the data:

```
    struct variabile {
        char* nome;         
        char* contenuto;        
        struct variabile* next;     
        int tipo;           
    };
```

And here is the code:

```
    struct variabile* pt = malloc (sizeof (struct variabile));
            pt->nome = $1; 
            pt->tipo = type; 
            pt->contenuto = $2; 
            pt->next=NULL;      


    if (testaVariabile == NULL) 
            testaVariabile=pt; 
    else {
            struct variabile* current = testaVariabile;


        while ((current->next)!=NULL){  

            if(strcmp(current->nome, pt->nome)==0)
                                    fprintf (stderr, "warning: clash di nome di variabili %s \n", current->nome);
            current=(current->next); 
        }
        (current->next)=pt; 

        if(strcmp(current->nome, pt->nome)==0) 
                fprintf (stderr, "warning: clash di nome di variabili %s \n", current->nome);
    }
```

Here is the initial declaration of the variable *testaVariabile*.

```
       struct variabile* testaVariabile = NULL;
```

I get a segmentation fault error when I try to update the *next* value of *current* in the last line of code.
I have also verified that the code didn't enter the *while* cycle.

I'm pretty new to C, so please explain the answer.

Thank you

**EDIT**

The rest of the code is a Flex parser.

**EDIT**

A friend of mine tell me to debug using gdb. It comes out that the error cames out from

```
       strcmp(current->nome, pt->nome)
```

I'm really sorry for the time lost looking for the problem in the wrong place, but this is my first serious time with C and Flex.

Somebody knows how to get rid of this problem?

Ok, last update.

The checked answer solved the problem. 
But in this case there was also an error in the way that the lexer read the value from the file, so it was a two-part problem.

Comment: You didn't close your while.

Comment: Sorry, my error in copy-past the code

Comment: the part you show us looks good. post the actual code or use gdb to debug your code.

Comment: As @perreal said, can you show us the *actual* code? What you show here is botched and not very clear. And unfortunately, our crystal balls aren't working because of a solar flare. You understand...

Comment: Make sure that current->nome and pt->nome are not null and valid strings.

Comment: Something tells me that the issue is that `testaVariabile` is stack-based and therefore always starts out as `NULL`.

Comment: @NikBougalis, but then it wouldn't execute the `else` part

Comment: @perreal I tested just now. I printed out the strings and they are valid. But on 4 inputs it prints only the first 2 than pop up the segmentation error.

Comment: @perreal I'm sorry, but I don't get what you mean...

Comment: @perreal do we know that the `else` part is executing? Marco only said that he verified the `while` doesn't execute.

Comment: @NikBougalis, just assumed that because Marco sail it seg faults @`(current->next)=pt;`.

Comment: The code enter in the **else** part, I'v tested it.

Comment: Beisde @perreal I've tried your solution, but it throws seg faults immediately

Comment: This is **not** the code you are running, because in **this** code the `else` clause is never executed. Also, in **this** code `(current->next)=pt` cannot segfault because the operation immediately before it accesses `current->next` (unless `current->next` is readable but not writable).

Comment: @JimBalter sorry for the problem with the else. In a previous editing I forgot to move the declaration of *testaVariabile*, you were right.
But as I told before, it seems that the code never enter the *while*, so the piece of code you are referring is never used.

Comment: You can't get to the statement after the `while` without executing the `while`. You almost certainly are misinterpreting the output from your debugger (you are using one, right?) See @perreal's answer for the probable real cause of your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
struct variabile* pt = malloc (sizeof (struct variabile));
pt->nome = malloc(strlen($1) + 1);
strcpy(pt->nome, $1); 
pt->tipo = type; 
pt->contenuto = $2; // maybe the same for this too?
pt->next=NULL;

/* rest of your code ... */
```

just a wild guess though

Comment: That certainly does fix a bug.